# Inserting <style> tags from a string in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, prototypejs

I'm loading a string via AJAX that reads like

```
<style>[some definitions]</style>
<h1>Lots of Markup</h1>
<p>follows here</p>
```

Using Webkit/Gecko everything works as expected — the markup is inserted, styles are applied. In IE (8) though the style-definitions are ignored. Actually, if you use the developer tools they are gone.

You can see in this JS-Fiddle that it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/J4Yzr/

Also, I've seen that trick that you create a temporary DOM-Object, set it's innerHTML to your markup and extract your markup as DOM-Objects from your temporary element. That doesn't work with style tags (if I did it right, I'm using prototypeJS):

```
var text = '<style>h1{color:red;}</style> style added',
    el   = new Element('div').update(text);

console.log(el.firstChild);
//is a HTMLStyleElement in Webkit but a [object Text] in IE
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how to properly apply the `<style>` in IE if you get it from such a string?

Comment: Is that prototype.js syntax? If so add a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's crazy. Add a `<br/>`-Tag in front of your string and it works in Internet Explorer.

```
<br/><style>[some definitions]</style><h1>Lots of Markup</h1>
```

You don't even need to create that temporary DOM-Object to insert code into. Just append it in your site.

What I'm doing now it insert the code with a `<br/>`-Tag and remove the `<br/>` afterwards. It's messy but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so I tried your solution, but guess what? When I stripped the 
 out after rendering markup retrieved via Ajax, the  tags disappeared from the DOM!  Back to square one.

So my solution is to prepend this instead:

```
<hr style='display:none'/>
```

Which did the trick nicely.  Thank you so much for solving this issue.